# C++ initialization with interface

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a general `value` class in C++ that can contain integer, float, and fractions, etc. So I wrote an interface `value_interface` and had `int` wrapped up in `int_wrapper` to inherit from the interface.

However, `value(3)` will not initialize a `value` object, because even if `3` is convertable to `int_wrapper`, which is convertable to `value_interface`, `value_interface` is not directly convertable to `value`. Is there a way to make `value(3)` possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <string>

class value_interface {
public:
    virtual std::string to_string() const = 0;
    virtual ~value_interface() {}
};

class value {
    std::shared_ptr<value_interface> d_ptr_;
public:
    value(value_interface* x) { d_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<value_interface>(x); }
    std::string to_string() const { return d_ptr_->to_string(); }
};

class int_wrapper : public value_interface {
    int val_;
public:
    int_wrapper(const int val) : val_(val) {}
    operator int() const { return val_; }
    std::string to_string() const override { return std::to_string(val_); }
    friend value operator+(int_wrapper x, int_wrapper y);
};

int main() {
    value a = 3; // Error    C2440    'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'value'
    int_wrapper b = 3; // ok
    value_interface& c = static_cast<value_interface&>(b); // ok
    value d = &c; // ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that is you read the error message thoroughly (something we can't, always include error messages, copy-pasted as text, in full and complete), I'm sure part of the problem should be quite clear.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is a template class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not really cuz I would like to define arithmitic operations later, which relies on the type information.For example fractions and integers are summed in a different way

Comment: @sunnycat Not really a problem cuz templates can be specialized for certain types, ya know.

Comment: You'll find [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) useful.

Comment: We have a clear separation here on SO between questions and answers. I have rolled back your edit which added answer information into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `make_value` templated function with specialisations for each class. e.g:

```
template < typename T >
value make_value( const T& t );

template <>
value make_value< int >( const int& i )
{
  return value{ std::make_shared< int_wrapper >( i ) };
}
```

Alternatively you can template the value constructor which will allow you to do `value v = 3` directly:

```
class value {
    std::shared_ptr<value_interface> d_ptr_;
public:
    value(value_interface* x) { d_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<value_interface>(x); }
    template < typename T >
    value( const T& t );
    std::string to_string() const { return d_ptr_->to_string(); }
};

template <>
value::value< int >( const int& i )
:d_ptr_(std::make_shared<int_wrapper>(i))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But is there anyway to write `value(3)` directly?